# Problema com checkedListBox + drag-n-drop

Tags: c#, .net, listbox

Bom dia, estou com um problema com o componente `checkedListBox` da minha aplicação *C# Windows Form*. No código a seguir estou usando *drag n drop* para reordenar os itens da `checkedListBox`, o que esta funcionando corretamente. Porém não consigo marcar como **check** nenhum item. Acho que o problema está no evento `MouseDown` mas não estou conseguindo corrigir. Alguém pode me ajudar com esse problema?

EDIT: código atualizado e funcionando corretamente.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace projetodetestes
{
public partial class testeeacelerometro : Form
{
    public testeeacelerometro()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    bool teste_checked = false;

    private void testeeacelerometro_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkedListBox1.AllowDrop = true;
        checkedListBox1.CheckOnClick = true;
    }

    private void checkedListBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Point point = checkedListBox1.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        int index = this.checkedListBox1.IndexFromPoint(point);
        if (index < 0) index = this.checkedListBox1.Items.Count - 1;
        object data = this.checkedListBox1.SelectedItem;
        this.checkedListBox1.Items.Remove(data);
        this.checkedListBox1.Items.Insert(index, data);
        if (teste_checked == true) checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(index, true);
        else return;
    }

    private void checkedListBox1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
    }

    private void checkedListBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.checkedListBox1.SelectedItem != null && e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            int index = checkedListBox1.SelectedIndex;
            if (checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(index)) teste_checked = true;
            this.checkedListBox1.DoDragDrop(this.checkedListBox1.SelectedItem, DragDropEffects.Move);            
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Isso está acontecendo porque você usou `checkedListBox1.CheckOnClick = false;`

Comment: não é, eu tentei deixar true mas qnd ele entra no evento MouseDown ele começa o drag drop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Infelizmente não há muitas soluções. Há uma gambiarra que funciona parcialmente.

Remova o evento `MouseDown` e insira o evento `MouseMove` desta forma:

```
private void checkedListBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.checkedListBox1.SelectedItem != null && e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        this.checkedListBox1.DoDragDrop(this.checkedListBox1.SelectedItem, DragDropEffects.Move);
}
```

Edit: Digo que funciona parcialmente, pois qualquer movimentação do mouse (com o botão esquerdo pressionado) já ativa o `DragDrop`.